# Nginx alias and php-fastcgi: No input file specified

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have domain configured as followed:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    root   /var/www/domains/somedomain/root;

    location = /service/alias/ {
        alias /var/www/service/alias/;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I want to execute the `index.php` file in `/var/www/service/alias/` when someone requests http://example.com/service/alias. I've tried many variations (putting the FastCGI parameters in the location and supply the full path for the `index.php` script), but i keep getting "No input file specified" errors from php-fastcgi.

Anyone an idea of what i'm doing wrong? Or at least how can Ii log the full errors of php-fastcgi?

Comment: why `location = /..` not `location /..` ?

Comment: The = is there because i only want to serve index.php on /service/shareboard/. Any other requests to /service/shareboard/ needs to go to my original root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` is [better in a server scope](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Multiple_Index_Directives) because then all other locations will inheret that value, especially if they are multiple index that are equal, and I like my php block to be as minimal as possible because most other options are already included in `fastcgi_params`, and I also believe that `fastcgi_pass` should be passed to an `http://` not IP directly, so try this version and tell me if it works for you.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  # added a server name, unless it's a catch all virtual host
  # then you better use `default_server` with `listen`
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/domains/somedomain/root;
  # index moved here
  index index.php;
  location = /service/alias/ {
    # why `=` ? I would remove it unless there's a purpose
    # index removed from here
    alias /var/www/service/alias/;
  }
  location ~* \.php$ {
    #removed all other options
    include fastcgi_params;
    # added `http` before `127.0.0.1`
    fastcgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

Comment: The = is there because i only want to serve index.php on /service/shareboard/. Adding HTTP before the fastcgi gives me warnings , and it still doesnt work.

Comment: what kind of doesn't work is it, 404? 500? 502? empty white page ?

Comment: No input file specified

Comment: I don't know if you solved this or not, if so tell us what you did.

Comment: I still did not fix it.

Comment: try adding this to the php location `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;`